# can't find .nii files

Tags: python, windows

I'm trying to load .nii-files with the nibabel library and am running into the following error with the .nii-files:

```py
>>> path = '..\\..\\data\\raw\\data\\images\\AD\\female\\002_S_0938\\MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled\\2006-10-05_15_54_26.0\\S19852\\ADNI_002_S_0938_MR_MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled_Br_20070219175406282_S19852_I40980.nii'

>>> with open(Path(path), 'rb') as f:
>>>    print('great success!')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '..\\..\\data\\raw\\data\\images\\AD\\female\\005_S_1341\\MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled\\2007-03-07_12_44_49.0\\S27673\\ADNI_005_S_1341_MR_MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled_Br_20070717180348670_S27673_I60417.nii'
```

And with the test-file:

```py
>>> path =  '..\\..\\data\\raw\\data\\images\\AD\\female\\002_S_0938\\MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled\\2006-10-05_15_54_26.0\\S19852\\test.txt'

>>> with open(Path(path), 'rb') as f:
>>>    print('great success!') 
great success!
```

Alternatively, the problem still exists with the library designed to read .nii-files:

```py
>>> import nibabel as nib
>>> path = '..\\..\\data\\raw\\data\\images\\AD\\female\\002_S_0938\\MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled\\2006-10-05_15_54_26.0\\S19852\\ADNI_002_S_0938_MR_MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled_Br_20070219175406282_S19852_I40980.nii'

>>> nib.load(path)
FileNotFoundError: No such file or no access: '..\..\data\raw\data\images\AD\female\005_S_1341\MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled\2007-03-07_12_44_49.0\S27673\ADNI_005_S_1341_MR_MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled_Br_20070717180348670_S27673_I60417.nii'
```

And with the test file:

```py
>>> path = '..\\..\\data\\raw\\data\\images\\AD\\female\\002_S_0938\\MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled\\2006-10-05_15_54_26.0\\S19852\\test.txt'

>>> nib.load(path)
ImageFileError: Empty file: '..\..\data\raw\data\images\AD\female\002_S_0938\MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled\2006-10-05_15_54_26.0\S19852\test.txt'
```

which in my opinion is strange behavior as the library finds the text file but not the .nii file, which exists in the same directory.

Note:

- the .nii files are not corruputed as I can open them in a separate program with no problem.
- I operate a windows OS

Update:

Current file structure:
[image: File Structure]

Full traceback:

[image]

Comment: If the computer says the file doesn't exist, I'd be more inclined to trust it than you. A common beginner error is to have Windows hide extensions and then be surprised when `file.nii` was _actually_ named `file.nii.txt` or something like that. Voting to close as lacking sufficient debugging details (i.e. information about which files _exactly_ exist in that directory, and perhaps an investigation into a permissions problem).

Comment: What files are in the list when you call: `os.listdir('..\\..\\data\\raw\\data\\images\\AD\\female\\002_S_0938\\MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled\\2006-10-05_15_54_26.0\\S19852\\')`?

Comment: @tripleee.  I checked your suggestions and updated my question accordingly. But as I wrote, the files can be _found_ and opened by another program which is used to visualize the content of a .nii-file. Maybe a problem with the filename itself?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay It returns the two files as seen in the newly added image: `['ADNI_002_S_0938_MR_MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled_Br_20070219175406282_S19852_I40980.nii',
 'test.txt']`

Comment: Okay, so you've definitely got the full filepath correct. Something strange must be going on inside `nib.load`. All I can suggest you do in use a debugger to step inside `nib.load(path)` and see what it does with the `path`. The exception suggests it somehow ends up becoming `'../(...)'`.

Comment: Did you try `nib.load(os.path.abspath(path))` ? See https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath .

Comment: @GordonAitchJay  Thanks for your reply. I've tried your suggestions. The problem is not library specific and the path is not changed. I've updated my question with another example and added the full traceback.

Comment: @JosefZ Thanks for your reply. The relative path is not the problem. I've updated my question with another example and added the full traceback.

Comment: Very strange. So it can read the text file in the same directory, but not the `.nii` file. What version of Python and Windows are you using. The issue might be related to the long filepath. Rename `ADNI_002_S_0938_MR_MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled_Br_20070219175406282_S19852_I40980.nii` to `ADNI.nii`. Does that work?

Comment: @GordonAitchJay Jep! The pathlength was the problem. My windows installation has a limit of 260 Characters (which can be disabled in the registry). Do you want to submit an answer? I would approve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `os.listdir('..\\..\\data\\raw\\data\\images\\AD\\female\\002_S_0938\\MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled\\2006-10-05_15_54_26.0\\S19852\\')` returns both files, and you can open the file `test.txt` but not `'ADNI_002_S_0938_MR_MPR__GradWarp__B1_Correction__N3__Scaled_Br_20070219175406282_S19852_I40980.nii'`, it suggests the issue might be related to the long filepath.

The 260 character limit can be disabled by setting this registry key to `1`: `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled`

See [Enable Long Paths in Windows 10, Version 1607, and Later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation?tabs=cmd#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later)